# Jackson : Pojo property multitype

Tags: java, jackson, pojo, json-deserialization, spring-android

I use **Jackson** Library for serialization/deserialization.

I have a Pojo class with a property that i'm looking to be an `Array` and also support an `object` (through annotation if possible, for example : *@Support(Actualite)* )  in the same-time.

```
@JsonProperty @Support(Actualite)
    private ArrayList<Actualite> actualites;
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Please elaborate the question with an example so we can understand in a better way.

Comment: @Sudhakar hope it's clear now

Comment: What do you mean by 'support an object'? Btw: There is no `@Support` annotation defined by Jackson.

Comment: @DirkLachowski i mean that i can deseiralize an Actualite instance (`{`... }`) into my variable : `actualities`

Comment: @Editor i m looking to annotation not through code. Thank you

Comment: @Mena i'm looking to do this through annotation

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking for is for Jackson to support a property as both an array, and an object for when there is only one value, eg

```
{ people : { name : "sam" } }
```

and

```
{ people : [ { name : "sam" }, { name : "bob" } ] }
```

In which case you'll want to add this to your mapper:

```
  mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED, true);
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

*Edit for Spring*

You should be able to do something like this if you are using RestTemplate in Spring for Android:

```
// use false to turn off the default converts
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(false);

// create a new converter with the required features
MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED, true);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

// register that as your converter
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converter);
```

Comment: i need an annotation please .. because i use Spring for android that integrate jackson mapper :)

Comment: There must be a way of configuring the mapper that spring for android uses, or providing your own.

Comment: Are you using RestTemplate?

Comment: yes i use RestTemplate

Comment: i get problem into converter.setObjectMapper(mapper); ??

Comment: What's the error message

Comment: any error they till me add build path

Comment: That's not very useful. What's the actual error.

Comment: you can check http://postimg.org/image/flugpuadv/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52540/discussion-between-abdellah-selassi-and-monkjack)